# Reduce the table fragmentation Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table with n elements with ids from 1 to n. Then I delete nearly all the data from the table, leaving only m elements, m << n, including element with id=n. Before deleting the difference between ids of adjacent rows was 1, now it could be much larger. I need to update the table such a way that remaining element ids were from 1 to m and difference between ids of adjacent rows was 1. How I can do this? I use PostgreSQL.

Comment: If `id` is the primary key, then you don't need to do anything. The **only** job of a primary key is to be unique. The actual value is completely meaningless and gaps are nothing to worry about.

Comment: Please clearly state if you want to *reorganize* your table after *deletes* or *renumerate* your keys and remove *gaps*. You use wording that allows both possibilities.

Comment: I need to renumerate keys and remove gaps

Comment: Then edit the question to clarify it. E.g. "Update Primary Key to eliminate Gaps". *Table fragmentation* is way a different topic. If you add a simple example with a table structure and sample data - the better.

Answer (score 0):

You may find a better option to **not update** the *primary key* (especially in heavy multiuser einvironment) but to *delegate* the removal of the gaps to the accessing view.

**Simple Example**

```
create table test as
select id from generate_series(1,5) id;

delete from test 
where id in (2,3,4);
```

The view assigns teh new continuous sequence using the  `row_number` function.

```
create view test_gapless as
select 
id,
row_number() over (order by id) gapless_id
from test;

select * from test_gapless;

id, gapless_id
1   1
5   2
```